# How do you calculate the higher order deriviative of $x^n$?

Tags: calculus

I need some help figuring this out:

$$D^n x^n  =\ ?$$

$$D^1 x^n = n  x ^{n-1} $$

$$D^2 x^n = n(n-1) x^{n-2}$$

$$D^n-1 =\ ???$$

Where does the $2$ go? and why does $x^n$ become $x$?

http://youtu.be/4sTKcvYMNxk?t=44m33s

Comment: Suggestion: Do a few cases, like the third derivative of $x^3$, the fourth derivative of $x^4$. Everything should become clear.

Comment: Ok, I just did it but i'm still unclear in the video, where the 2 is coming from? how is he deducing x^1?

Comment: Since
$$D^k_xx^n=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)x^{n-k}$$,
we have
\begin{align}
D^{n-1}_x x^n
&=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-(n-1)+2))(n-(n-1)+1)x^{n-(n-1)}\\
&=n(n-1)(n-2)...(3)(2)x\\
\end{align}

Comment: Do $x^4$. First $4x^3$. Next, $(4)(3)(x^2)$. Next $(4)(3)(2)x$. That's the $2$, it indicates it's almost over. One more step.

Comment: Thank you. I finially understand it. It's just n factorial.

Answer (score 4):

We see that
\begin{align}
D_xx^n&=nx^{n-1}\\
D^2_xx^n&=n(n-1)x^{n-2}\\
D^3_xx^n&=n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}\\
D^4_xx^n&=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)x^{n-4}\\
\end{align}
and so on. We may deduce that
$$D^k_xx^n=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)x^{n-k}$$
Therefore,
$$D^n_xx^n=n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-n+1)x^{n-n}=n!$$

Comment: No induction or something needed?

Comment: You can do a formal proof by induction if you really want to. But since the pattern is quite obvious it might not be necessary to go through the extra trouble. Simply deduce the pattern and you get your answer.